# Maven Source Code Dependencies

Tags: maven-2

I have a couple of projects that I'm working on in Eclipse (or any IDE, so I don't want to depend on specific eclipse dependency maven capabilities). Some projects depend on other projects. Typically in Eclipse I would add the projects as references to other projects, but I'm not sure how to handle this when using Maven. In the deployment environment, there will be jars created and the maven build can pull the latest jars from the repository. Is there a way to reference another project's source code using maven while in the dev environment? For example...

I have this scenario:
Project A depends on B

I need to make a change to B and that will require an update to A. I don't want to make the change to B and check it in without checking in A since that will break A. And I would like to manage these dependencies through Maven -- any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [maven 2 eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/) has 'workspace dependency resolution', where the dependencies are first looked up in the workspace, and then in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use SNAPSHOT version when doing my development.  Project A depends on the latest SHAPSHOT version of Project B, so when I change Project B, I have Team City recompile and push out a new SHAPSHOT artifact to artifactory.  Then I clean and compile project A to get the new Project B.